# How to search a hard drive for a directory name using Windows batch file and strip only the directory name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am building a .bat file that requires me to find a directory on a hard drive.

I have used the dir command to output the following:

G:>dir woff.exe /s /b

G:\OBDSoftware\WOFF\OBDWW1 Over Flanders Fields\WOFF.exe

I want to store this info in a variable and then possibly use findstr to strip out the "WOFF.exe" portion of the above string and only save the first part "G:\OBDSoftware\WOFF\PBDWW1 Over Flanders Fields\" in another variable for further use. I am having difficulty understanding how to do this.

I would appreciate some help as I am rather new to batch files.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

**EDIT**

I added `"delims="` to the `FOR` command to handle spaces in the paths.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('dir woff.exe /s /b') DO SET myvar=%%~dI%%~pI
SET myvar=%myvar:~0,-1%
```

Then you can use `%myvar%` to access the stored file path.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to throw away "\WOFF.exe" instead of "WOFF.exe". Is your solution still appropriate?

Comment: I ran your first line of code in a cmd window and got the following output which was missing the last directory level "PBDWW1 Over Flanders Fields". here is the output I got: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\rwiggins>g:

G:\>for /f %I in ('dir woff.exe /s /b') do set OBDpath=%~dI%~pI

G:\>set OBDpath=G:\OBDSoftware\WOFF\

G:\>

Comment: I just ran your latest code and here is what I see:

Comment: Please ignore last comment I took to long and it timed out before I was finished.I just ran your latest code and here is what I see:


g:\>FOR /F %I IN ('dir woff.exe /s /b') DO SET myvar=%~dI%~pI

g:\>SET myvar=g:\OBDSoftware\WOFF\

g:\>SET myvar=g:\OBDSoftware\WOFF

g:\>echo OBDpath=g:\OBDSoftware\WOFF
OBDpath=g:\OBDSoftware\WOFF

g:\>set /p finish=type "x" after you do a save of the contents of this window
type "x" after you do a save of the contents of this window

Comment: These comments windows are difficult to post results in a nice format. It seems that your code drops the portion of the directory name called "OBDWW1 Over Flanders Fields" and only leaves "G:\OBDSoftware\WOFF"

Comment: when I do the following "dir woff.exe /s /b" here is what I see: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\rwiggins>g:

G:\>dir woff.exe /s /b
G:\OBDSoftware\WOFF\OBDWW1 Over Flanders Fields\WOFF.exe

G:\>

Comment: Try the updated code. The file I was testing with didn't have any spaces in the path, so I didn't handle that situation.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks aphoria for all your help. I have been struggling with this for a long time on my own and you resolved it so quickly in spite of my inept responses here. Your assistance is so greatly appreciated and you gave me some insight into the use of the "for" syntax, modifiers and delims use. Thanks again

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. You can click the check mark beside the answer to show that it answered your question.